# An Upper bound for the number of independent events

Tags: probability

Assume Ω is a finite probability space (|Ω|=n),
So There are at most $\log_2 n$ non-trivial  different independent events.

I need to prove this but I actually don’t understand why it is true.

Comment: For intuition... consider flipping $k$ independent fair coins.  There are $2^k$ different outcomes and the $k$ different independent events corresponding to the outcomes of each respective coin.

Comment: @JMoravitz ... and to complete the problem, drop the word "fair"